# QComboBox::findData() always returns -1

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qtgui

I am trying to get the id of the record in the model from a `QCombobox` with findData(index), but when select a item, it retunrs -1. It has been working in another project, but this is the second one that doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
modAnfi = new QSqlTableModel(this);
modAnfi->setQuery("SELECT id, (nombres || ' ' || apellidos) as Nombre, nombres, apellidos FROM tbPersonas WHERE activo=1");
comboAnfitrion->setModel(modAnfi);
comboAnfitrion->setModelColumn(1);
comboAnfitrion->setEditable(true);
comboAnfitrion->completer()->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);

connect(comboAnfitrion, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(currentIndexChangeAnfitrion(int)));
```

and:

```
void controlReg::currentIndexChangeAnfitrion(int index)
{

    qDebug() << comboAnfitrion->findData(index); // -1
    qDebug()<< comboAnfitrion->itemData(1); // QVariant(Invalid) 
}
```

Thanks for your time, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the model you assign to the comboBox, use the index to look for it:
 `modAnfi->data(modAnfi->index( index, 0));`

Comment: Thank you, bluesky777, i don't know why itemData doesn't allways work for me, but with model->data, and passing the index, it works for me. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [QComboBox documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.htm); from the `findData` description, quoting:

> Returns the index of the item containing the given data

Where you are passing `index` as the "given data". However, index is already an index in the combobox. But you're obviously not looking for an index (since you already have one).

I suspect you actually want to call the `itemData` method instead? That would retrieve the data associated with an element for a given index.

Comment: You're right about findData, and the docu says that i need itemData, but see my example, it shows invalid, now i see that whith Qt::DisplayRole it retunrs the index!! why? maybe the query? how do i especifie the column that has the primary key in the Combobox or... i donk know. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, i'll explain correctly: When i use just findData returns -1; findData with Qt::displayRole returns the index; when i use itemData returns QVariant(Invalid); AND when i use itemData with Qt::DisplayRole returns QVariant(Qstring, "Name And LastName"). I need the id of the selected item, how do i retrieve it? thank u very much.